# SolidColorBrush with Opacity on a Black background

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am doing the following to fill a rectangle with a certain opacity.

```
 SolidColorBrush fillColor = new SolidColorBrush(myColor);
 fillColor.Opacity = 0.3;
 rectangle1.Fill = fillColor;
```

The rectangle is part of a user control that is on a Black background. The problem is that I am getting the opacity on a White background. How to change it as if opacity is applied on the color on a Black background.

The following is the color I get for a green color fill.
[image] (i.e as overlaid on white background) What I need is something like this. [image]  (i.e as overlaid on black background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question is years old I know but maybe this will help someone.  This is what I did in XAML/VB visual studio 2017. This works great:

```
Private Sub Hyper1_PointerEntered(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Hyper1.PointerEntered
    Hyper1.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold)
    Hyper1.Background.Opacity = 0.6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
myColor.A = 75; // 255 * 0.3 is approx. 75
SolidColorBrush fillColor = new SolidColorBrush(myColor);
rectangle.Fill = fillColor;
```

Comment: This is not changing the opacity, just changing the color.